# Are Spark PairRDDs and DataFrames Indexed?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, rdd

When I perform a transform like

```
pairedRdd1.join(pairedRdd2)
```

or

```
dataframe1.join(dataframe2, dataframe1.one == dataframe2.one)
```

Is every element in the first PairRDD or DataFrame compared with every element in the second or is it done more efficiently?  Based on my understanding of how Spark's storage works the answer is the former.  But I've been lead to believe that there is some kind of Spark magic that's makes the lookups much faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither standard RDDs nor DataFrames are indexed. To perform `joins` on `PairwiseRDDs` and equality joins on `DataFrames` Spark is using partitioning. It can either leverage existing partitioner or if one doesn't exist apply partitioning as the part of the `join` operation.

It means that equality based joins require comparisons only for well defined pairs, not a full Cartesian product. At the partition level this can be further improved by using `coGroup` like operation (RDDs) or `SortMergeJoin` (`DataFrames`).

It doesn't mean that indexing on distributed data structures is not possible. There are tools in Spark ecosystem which provide indexing on top of Spark ([`IndexedRDD`](https://github.com/amplab/spark-indexedrdd)) or use external indexing ([`IgniteRDD`](https://apacheignite-fs.readme.io/docs/ignitecontext-igniterdd#section-running-sql-queries-against-ignite-cache)). Finally compressed columnar storage can be used to perform efficient lookups on unindexed data.

Regarding `lookup` operations on `PairwiseRDD` all depends on a partitioner:

- if RDD had no partitioner `lookup` is equivalent to `filter`.
- if RDD has a partitioner behavior is similar to the lookup on hash table with separate chaining. First we determine a bucket (partition) and then perform linear lookup over its iterator.